# SQL constraint in populating attribute table

Tags: qgis, sql

In QGIS' attribute table I have an integer field and a string field and I want to populate the string field depending on a certain value in the integer field. I tried to use a simple SQL command:

```
CASE
WHEN int_field = 1
THEN string_field = 'London'
ELSE string_field
END
```

but it doesn't work. I had to copy the values from the integer to the string field and then convert them with another `CASE WHEN` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bad SQL error. When uploading a field in QGIS with the Open field calculator it is not necessary to repeat the field name in the `THEN` clause:

```
CASE
WHEN int_field = 1
THEN 'London'
ELSE string_field
END
```